# Angular unit tesing HTTP interceptor that appends XCSRF token in header

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-http-interceptors, angular-unit-test

I am unit testing global HTTP interceptor that gets the XSCRF token from a service call  **getReponse()** and appends it to the header only in POSTS request **postResponse()** call ( service call mentioned below )

So far I tried testing it but i am not able to pass the test case. Any help would be much appreciated.

This is the **optout.service.ts** file which contains two methods

> getResponse() method uses mergeMap to chain two calls, first service call is to get the token for XCSRF and the second to get the form response

```
 getReponse():Observable<optout>{
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(`https://thisIsGetTokenApi.com`).pipe(
     mergeMap(token=>this.httpClient.get<optout>(`https://someurlenpoint2.com`))
  )

  postResponse(data:optout):Observable<optout>{
    return this.httpClient.post<optout>('https://api-endpoint',data)
    }
```

Here is ***global-http-interceptor.ts*** file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpErrorResponse, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class GlobalHttpInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  public hostURL=environment.hostURL;
  public apiURL=environment.apiURL;

  constructor(public router: Router) { }

  token:string='';
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if(this.token && req.method== "POST"){
      req=req.clone({headers:req.headers.append('X-CSRF-TOKEN',this.token)});
    }
    return next.handle(req)
    .pipe(
        tap(event => {
          if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            if(req.url.includes('/getToken')){
            this.token=event.body.XCSRFTOKEN;
          }
        }
      }, (error:any) => {
          if(error instanceof HttpErrorResponse){
            if(error.status === 400 || error.status === 401 || error.status === 402){
            window.location.href=`https://some-direct-url.com`;
            }
          }
        })
      )
    }
  }
```

**This is test spec file global-http-interceptor.spec.ts that i tried**

```
import { fakeAsync, TestBed, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { GlobalHttpInterceptorService } from './global-http-interceptor.service';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { OptoutService } from './optout.service';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { API_CONFIG_TOKEN } from '../token';
import { GlobalConstants } from '../global-constants';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { optout } from '../model/optoutModel';

describe('GlobalHttpInterceptorService', () => {
  let apiURL=environment.apiURL;
  let httpController: HttpTestingController;
  let getPreferenceApi='http://somegetrequestapi/v1/get';
  let updatePreferenceApi='http://getpostrequest/v1/post';

  let service: GlobalHttpInterceptorService;
  let optoutService: OptoutService;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports:[RouterTestingModule, HttpClientTestingModule ],
      providers:[
        OptoutService,
        {provide:HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,useClass:GlobalHttpInterceptorService,multi:true},
        {provide:API_CONFIG_TOKEN,useValue:{useFcvApi:false}},
      ]
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(GlobalHttpInterceptorService);
    optoutService =TestBed.inject(OptoutService);
    httpMock=TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should add an XCSRF header',() => {
    const optoutMock:optout={
      "output": {
            "somevar1": "somvalue",
            "somevar2": false
          },{
            "somevar1": "somvalue2",
            "somevar2": false
          }
    }

    optoutService.getResponse().subscribe(res=>{
      expect(res).toBeTruthy();
    })

    optoutService.postResponse(optoutMock).subscribe(res=>{
      expect(res).toBeTruthy();
    })

    const httpRequest=httpMock.expectOne(getTokenApi);
    expect(httpRequest.request.headers.has('X-CSRF-TOKEN')).toEqual(true);

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the addition of the token is being blocked because `this.token` is falsy (not truthy)?

```
// this token right here
if(this.token && req.method== "POST"){
      req=req.clone({headers:req.headers.append('X-CSRF-TOKEN',this.token)});
    }
```

If so, try setting it and see if the test passes:

```
service.token = 'abc';
optoutService.postResponse(optoutMock).subscribe(res=>{
      expect(res).toBeTruthy();
    })

    const httpRequest=httpMock.expectOne(getTokenApi);
    expect(httpRequest.request.headers.has('X-CSRF-TOKEN')).toEqual(true);
```